# Как связать слот виджета с сигналом используемого класса?

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет, имеется виджет MainWindow и класс finder. Как можно связать слот виджета MainWindow с сигналом класса finder?
 В классе finder объявил сигнал 
    signals:
    void redraw();

В MainWindow объявил создал переменную с классом

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "QtWidgets"
#include <Qpainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <finder.h>

finder robot;
```

Далее в конструкторе MainWindow пытаюсь соединить сигнал класса finder и слот из MainWindow следующим образом:

```
connect(& robot, SIGNAL(redraw()), this, SLOT(update()));
```

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: По тому коду, что представлен сейчас, всё выглядит нормально. Покажите сообщение компилятора об ошибке.

Comment: @aleks.andr 
C:\Qt\LabrynthWidget\Labrinth\mainwindow.cpp:18: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(finder*, const char*, MainWindow*, const char*)'
     connect(& robot, SIGNAL(redraw()), this, SLOT(update()));
                                                            
18 строка - connect(& robot, SIGNAL(redraw()), this, SLOT(update()));
Возможно я упустил один момент, класс finder не является Q_OBJECT (вроде можно соединять сигналы и слоты только у классов унаследованных от QOjbect?)

Comment: Вы сам дали ответ на ваш вопрос: **можно соединять сигналы и слоты только у классов унаследованных от QObject**.

Comment: @aleks.andr  
В заголовочном файле класса finder добавил:  
#include <QObject> 
9. class finder : public QObject  
10. {  
11.     Q_OBJECT
Теперь компилятор выдает такую ошибку:  
C:\Qt\LabrynthWidget\Labrinth\finder.h:9: ошибка: undefined reference to `vtable for finder'

Comment: Долой глобальный экземпляр класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу минимальный компилируемый пример работы с сигналами-слотами:

**mobject.h**

```
#include <QObject>

class QString;

class MObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MObject(const QString &objName, QObject *parent = 0);

  void emitSignal();

signals:
  void testSignal();

public slots:
  void testSlot();

};
```

**mobject.cpp:**

```
#include <QDebug>

MObject::MObject(const QString &objName, QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent)
{
  setObjectName(objName);
}

void MObject::emitSignal()
{
  emit testSignal();
}

void MObject::testSlot()
{
  qDebug() << QString("%1::testSlot() call by %2 ")
              .arg(this->objectName())
              .arg(sender()->objectName());
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "mobject.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  MObject objA("objA");
  MObject objB("objB");

  QObject::connect(&objA, &MObject::testSignal, &objB, &MObject::testSlot);
  QObject::connect(&objB, &MObject::testSignal, &objA, &MObject::testSlot);

  objA.emitSignal();
  objB.emitSignal();

  return a.exec();
}
```

**Результат:**

```
"objB::testSlot() call by objA"
"objA::testSlot() call by objB"
```